# OpenCV webcam frames to OpenGL texture

Tags: c#, opencv, opengl, emgucv, opentk

I am working on C# and using `OpenTK`(OpenGL wrapper) and `EmguCV`(OpenCV wrapper).

What I want to do is easy to understand: Grab the webcam video stream and put it on a `GLControl`.

1. **I have a static `class` called `Capturer` which has a method that captures a frame and returns it as a `cv::Mat` wrapped object**:

   ```
   internal static void Initialize()
   {
       cap = new VideoCapture(1);
       cap.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Fps, 25);
       cap.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameWidth, 1920);
       cap.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameHeight, 1080);
   }

   internal static Mat GetCurrentFrame()
   {
       mat = cap.QueryFrame();
       if (!mat.IsEmpty)
       {
           return mat;
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```
2. **Now in my `GLControl` `Load event` I initialize the capturer and OpenGL**:

   ```
       Capturer.Initialize();

       GL.ClearColor(Color.Blue);
       GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);

       GL.Viewport(-glControl1.Width, -glControl1.Height, glControl1.Width * 2, glControl1.Height * 2);
   ```
3. **And finally, in the `GLControl` `Paint event`**:

   ```
       GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

       GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
       GL.LoadIdentity();

       Mat m = Capturer.GetCurrentFrame();
       if (m != null)
       {
           GL.GenTextures(1, out textureId);
           GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, this.textureId);

           GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (float)TextureMinFilter.Nearest);
           GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (float)TextureMagFilter.Linear);

           GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (float)TextureWrapMode.Clamp);
           GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (float)TextureWrapMode.Clamp);

           GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgb, 1920, 1080, 0, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgr, PixelType.UnsignedByte, m.DataPointer);
       }
       m.Dispose();

       glControl1.SwapBuffers();
       glControl1.Invalidate();
   ```

This is showing a full Blue screen. I think the error is on `m.DataPointer`.

(I have tried rendering the frames with `Bitmap` using the property `m.Bitmap`and it works but the performance is so bad.)

Comment: You are not drawing anything, so why do you expect something to appear?

Comment: Do you mean I need to draw a rectangle or something bounding the `GLControl`?

Comment: Yes,. Just copying data to a texuttre will n ot draw anything. You need to draw a textured quad, or you could blit the texture to the framebuffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing a rectangle bounding the `GLControl` solved it:

```
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);
                GL.TexCoord2(0, 0); GL.Vertex2(0, 0);
                GL.TexCoord2(0, 1); GL.Vertex2(0, 1);
                GL.TexCoord2(1, 1); GL.Vertex2(1, 1);
                GL.TexCoord2(1, 0); GL.Vertex2(1, 0);
            GL.End();
            m.Dispose();
```

Be sure to dispose the object after drawing the frame so you will not run out of memory.